# Why does "read" not iterate over the input string with a <<< stdin but does so with a pipe input in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin

```
A="Hello World. What is going on? "  
echo $A | while read -d " " a  
do  
echo $a  
done
```

The above program prints:
Hello
World.
What
is
going
on?

However, if I write :

```
A="Hello World. What is going on? "
while read -d " " a <<< $(echo $A)
do
echo $a
done
```

I get :
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

and it continues.

Why is this the case? In both case, I am feeding the string to the stdin of the command "while read -d " " a" but only in the first case it iterates over the words in the string while in the second case it is only stuck on first word in every loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you should feed the `while do ... done` loop, not `read` directly.

Try this:

```sh
A="Hello World. What is going on? "
while read -d ' ' a
do
    echo $a
done <<< "$A"
```

Note: You don't need `$(echo $A)` in the [*here-string*](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) that follows `<<<`. It's enough with `"$A"`.